# JBoss Configuration

Tags: java, linux, jboss

I have been tasked with setting up a server for running JBoss presumably the latest version.  I was wondering if anyone had any recommendations for setting up the disk partitions for a Linux (Red Hat) system?  Currently they are running the lab with everything on one partition, and I would like to avoid that going into production. Specifically I would like to know what partition should get the bulk of the space?

The system is brand new and features a Raid5 controller with 6 x 150 GB disks.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default JBoss puts files in:

```
%JBOSS_HOME%/server/default/data
%JBOSS_HOME%/server/default/log
%JBOSS_HOME%/server/default/tmp
%JBOSS_HOME%/server/default/work
```

The log folder size is unbounded.

I *think* both tmp and work are bounded by the size/quantity of applications you deploy.

I have no idea about data.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with JBoss configuration

Comment: Where would JBoss Home be if it was going to be on that system? Assuming defaults.